# How can I adjust the minimal width/height of an editor group in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

When you split a window or go multi view with multiple files, and you drag the bar all the way to one side... How can you adjust that minimum value?

Example: I have two files opened side by side. When I work on the one to the right, the left one collapses down to, say, 10%. So now the window is 10% left, 90% right. How can I adjust that 10% to be, say 5%? Is there a way to adjust this value in the preferences?

I couldn't find any settings, or it's labeled as something I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "`github vscode issues minimum editor group width OR height`" and found that this was raised as a feature-request in 2018: [Allow to configure the minimal width of an editor #54470](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54470), where it was closed as "out of scope" in 2018 with this message (emphasis added):

> This iteration we focus on issue grooming. This issue is being closed to keep the number of issues in our inbox on a manageable level, we are closing issues that are not going to be addressed in the foreseeable future: We look at the number of votes the issue has received and the number of duplicate issues filed. More details [here](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope). **If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.**